# How to fill in missing dates in range by group

Tags: r, dplyr, sqldf

I have a `data.frame` of groups and dates. How do I fill in all the missing dates in the min-max date range for each group?

Ideally I would do this in `dplyr`. But ultimately, I'd just like to do this efficiently with as few lines of (readable) code as possible. Below is a minimal example. I actually have many dates and groups. Both of my approaches look kind of ugly. There has to be a better way, right?

```
#### setup ####

library(sqldf)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(the_group = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=3), date = Sys.Date() + c(0:2, 1:3), stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  slice(-2) # represents that I may be missing data in a range!

#### dplyr approach with cross join dummy ####
full_seq <- data.frame(cross_join_dummy = 1, date = seq.Date(from=min(df$date), to=max(df$date), by = "day"))

range_by_group <- df %>%
  group_by(the_group) %>%
  summarise(min_date = min(date), max_date = max(date)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(cross_join_dummy = 1)

desired <- range_by_group %>%
  inner_join(full_seq, by="cross_join_dummy") %>%
  filter(date >= min_date, date <= max_date) %>%
  select(the_group, date)

#### sqldf approach ####
full_seq <- data.frame(date = as.character(seq.Date(from=min(df$date), to=max(df$date), by="day")))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(date = as.character(date))

range_by_group <- sqldf("
                  SELECT the_group, MIN(date) AS min_date, MAX(date) AS max_date
                  FROM df
                  GROUP BY the_group
                  ")

desired <- sqldf("
            SELECT rbg.the_group, fs.date
            FROM range_by_group rbg
            JOIN full_seq fs
              ON fs.date BETWEEN rbg.min_date AND rbg.max_date
            ")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) no packages - by**

This does not use any packages. `by` splits `df` by `df$the_group` and then performs the indicated operation on each one.  `do.call("rbind", ...)` puts the groups back together.

```
seq_date <- function(x) seq(min(x), max(x), by = "day")
do.call("rbind", by(df, df$the_group, with, 
  data.frame(the_group = the_group[1], date = seq_date(date))))
```

**2) data.table** Here is a solution using data.table.  `seq_date` is from (1)

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, list(date = seq_date(date)), by = the_group]
```

**3) tidyverse**  This uses `map_df` from purrr to apply the function given in formula notation over the groups and to put the result together into a data frame. `data_frame` is from the tibble package.  seq_date is from (1).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
   split(.$the_group) %>% 
   map_df(~ data_frame(the_group = .$the_group[1], date = seq_date(.$date)))
```

**4) tapply**

**4a) tapply - tidyr/reshape2**  `seq_date` is from (1).

```
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)

df %>%
   { tapply(.$date, .$the_group, seq_date, simplify = FALSE) } %>%
   melt %>%
   unnest
```

**4b) tapply - no packages**  The last line pieces together the output of `tapply` avoiding the need for any packages.  `seq_date` is from (1).

```
ta <- tapply(df$date, df$the_group, seq_date, simplify = FALSE)
data.frame(the_group = rep(names(ta), lengths(ta)), date = do.call("c", ta))
```

**4c) tapply - lattice** We can use the lattice package's `make.groups` on `ta` from (4b). lattice is pre-installed with R so it does not involve installing any additional packages.  Unfortunately `make.groups` removes the Date `class` attribute so we have to put it back.  Also `make.groups` uses `which` and `data` column names so we fix up the column names.

```
library(lattice)
with(do.call("make.groups", ta), 
  data.frame(the_group = which, date = structure(data, class = "Date")))
```

**4d) tapply - no packages - stack**   We can use `stack` to convert `ta` from (4b) to the desired form provided we remove the `"Date"` class first. Then after applying `stack` we can restore the `"Date"` class.  `stack` uses hard coded column names which we replace using `setNames`.

```
stack_dates <- function(x) 
  transform(stack(lapply(x, as.vector)), values = structure(values, class = "Date"))
setNames(stack_dates(ta)[2:1], c("the_group", "date"))
```

Comment: Still having trouble understanding why the "no packages" approach works. Especially with the `the_group[1]` and `with`

Comment: It's the same as `do.call("rbind", by(df, df$the_group, function(x)
  data.frame(the_group = x$the_group[1], date = seq(min(x$date), max(x$date), by = "day"))))` except we used `with` to shorten it.  `the_group` is constant within a group so we just used the first component as you can't mix two different length vectors in a data frame unless one of them has length 1.

Comment: A slightly expanded answer in light of improvements today (OCT 2017) would use `nest()` functionality instead of the split, and map combination the OP uses here for his `tidyverse` example. Slightly cleaner presentation. Otherwise, the logic here remains the same.